# Windows 2003 mandatory profile changes reverted only after workstation restarts

Tags: windows-server-2003, user-profile

I created a roaming mandatory profile, logged in as the user with the mandatory profile and made some changes to test it.

After I logged off and logged in again as the user, I saw that the changes were not reverted back to the mandatory profile.
**The profile on the server was not altered**.

I logged in as the administrator and tried to delete the profile, but when viewing it through **User Profiles** dialog in **System Properties** I am unable to make changes to it, as if the user is still logged in.

**Fast User Switching** service is set to 'Manual' and isn't running.

I reset the workstation and logged it as the user with the mandatory profile and the changes reverted back as supposed.

Why is the profile locked even when the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 2):

There are times when Windows doesn't unload the user registry hive when a user logs off, therefore the profile is still in use and can't be deleted. In those cases you can:

1. Reboot the workstation OR
2. Install the [User Profile Hive Cleanup Service](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6676) on the server.

In W2K8, the User Profile service handles this and is built in to the OS.

Comment: I think you mean reboot the Workstation. The broblem occurs on the WS not the server. I used this tool on some WS's, it seems to do the job.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Got mixed up there. Reboot the workstation. So you've installed the UPH service on a workstation and it works? I've never done that. I was referring to a TS when I posted my answer. I manage a farm  of TS servers so I got caught up thinking about roaming/mandatory profiles on a TS server.

Comment: UPH works on workstations.  In wa suggested to us by MS to resolve a roaming profile issue on XP.